# Can I manualy add modules in Drupal 7 just by pasting them in the modules folder?

Tags: 7, installation

I am unable to install modules in Drupal 7. I'm working on localhost so I don't have FTP, but it seems that they made it impossible to install them otherwise.

In Drupal 6 I would of just paste a module, refresh and there it was. Here I have to specify the FTP.

Comment: You should be able to paste a module into the modules directory in D7 just as you were in D6.  Is this not the case?

Comment: nop, it doesn't appear in the list..even if I paste it

Comment: Check permissions of the pasted files/directory and try clearing the cache?

Comment: I've added 777 permissions to all drupal, I use XAMPP for mac, is installed in /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/drupal-7.8. Clear cache didn't work... very wierd... I will try to reinstall Drupal and change the htdocs to my /Users folder.. I also looked what user uses the apache when it created the folders /sites/default/files and all... I've changed that as well ..nothing...

Comment: installing this in my dedicated server works.. can see all modules that I pasted.. but on local..nop...wierd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have a single site setup:**

Contrib modules go in /sites/all/modules/contrib/

Custom modules go in /sites/all/modules/custom/

Custom themes go in /sites/all/themes/

**If you have a multi site setup:**

contrib modules go in /sites/site_name/modules/contrib/

custom modules go in /sites/site_name/modules/custom/

custom themes go in /sites/site_name/themes/

I think some of the language in this post is dangerous, remember, do NOT put modules in the root modules directory, that is DRUPAL CORE.  Everything you code and download should go in the directories I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

About everything that you'd need to install a contributed module is explained in the following drupal.org article: [Installing contributed modules (Drupal 7)](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7)

You should be able to just copy/paste the module's folder into your Drupal 7 module folder. Make sure to check the file permissions on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the required module from Drupal
2. Unzip / Extract it and place it in /sites/all/modules/
3. Access Modules from Administrator end
4. Search for the new module and enable it.
5. You are done :)